# Parsing Individual Excel Cells and Extracting Information

Tags: excel, vba, parsing

I want to extract a product ID from each individual cell in a particular column. Here is what the contents of what some of the cell will look like:

> 3M? DBI-SALA® Ultra-Lok? Leading Edge Self Retracting Lifeline,
>   3504500C, 30 ft (9.1 m) galvanized steel cable

I want to extract the product number "3504500C" and have it listed next to the original cell that I have posted above. What makes this tricky is that the information in each cell is in a different format so the product number wont be in the same location.

If I have a comprehensive list of the products, is there a way that I can search each product in the comprehensive list against the cell and once a match is found, it will pull the product and put it into the adjacent cell. I would need this process to run for each individual cell.

Comment: The simple answer is yes. You could load the list in an array and search each line for what is in the array. There are other possibilities too. Write some code and ask again!

Comment: You need to find regularity, but you also need to know your other forms of data to find regularity. It's as simple as having a comma before and after the product number, and the only one before and after the product number.

Comment: If you have a comprehensive list in which the cell value can be found, and that list has the article number in its own cell, chances are that the cell value was created from that list, and that implies that it was created using a formula - meaning it must have regularity. Look for the position of commas and/or question marks. By the one item you give us the item number might be in the section following the second question mark, following the first comma.

Comment: If you use a named list of part numbers "PARTS" you can use something like this: `=IFERROR(INDEX(PARTS,MATCH(0,SEARCH(PARTS,A2),-1)),"")` entered as an array formula (using Ctrl+Shift+Enter) in a single cell and then filled down..  **PROVIDED**: no part number is a substring of another part number and no part number is a substring of a "non-part-number" piece of text.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work assuming the cell contents are split by comma into each product attribute. This works by storing the known product IDs into a dictionary, then look for them after splitting the cell up.

```
Private Const vbTextCompare As Long = 1

Public Function GetProductFromCell(Cell As Range) As String
    Dim CellParts   As Variant
    Dim CellPart    As Variant
    Dim ProductList As Object

    Set ProductList = GetProductList()
    CellParts = Split(Cell.Value, ",")
    GetProductFromCell = vbNullString

    For Each CellPart In CellParts
        If ProductList.exists(Trim$(CellPart)) Then
            GetProductFromCell = Trim$(CellPart)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function

Public Function GetProductList() As Object
    Set GetProductList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    GetProductList.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    'Add all products here
    GetProductList.Add "3504500A", "3504500A"
    GetProductList.Add "3504500B", "3504500B"
    GetProductList.Add "3504500C", "3504500C"
End Function
```